# QPixMap не отображает изображения .jpg

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, dll, jpeg

`QPixMap` не отображает изображения **.jpg** в *Pycharm*.

На других устройствах этот же код работает исправно, а у меня место картинки `label` остается пустым.

**.png** файлы открываются.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

*Qt* не может найти библиотеки форматов.

Скопируйте и положите рядом со своей программой (вместе с каталогом)

> ...\Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\

(в нем лежат **`qgif.dll`**, **`qjpeg.dll`** и т.п.)